# Expanding properties in custom ant task

Tags: java, ant, expand, properties-file

In my current ant build, I have a target which calls a Java class using a `refid` to specify a set of files.

I would like to be able to expand all Ant properties within the file prior to processing it (the same way the `sql` task has an `expandproperties` flag).

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, there is no built-in task for expanding properties in a file in-place; if you'd like to use only built-in features, you must use either the `copy` or `move` tasks along with the `filterchain` and `expandproperties` subtaks.

If you insist on an in-place replacement (that is: without using a temporary intermediary file), you'll have to develop your own task. Within the Ant API, you can use the `replaceProperties` method (on the `Project` instance) to expand a string.

Comment: Thanks. I should be able to work up a way to create a temp file with the expanded properties, switch operation to that file, and then clean up the extra files at the end.